# Mysql 8.0 and read-only not working as expected

Tags: mysql, replication, permissions, users, read-only-database

I have a new Master/Slave config running. Everything is happily replication. I have added a secondary user whose role will be to manage the databases and tables.

Currently the following privileges are set:

> ```
>          Select_priv: Y
>            Insert_priv: Y
>            Update_priv: Y
>            Delete_priv: Y
>            Create_priv: Y
>              Drop_priv: Y
>            Reload_priv: N
>          Shutdown_priv: N
>           Process_priv: N
>              File_priv: N
>             Grant_priv: N
>        References_priv: Y
>             Index_priv: Y
>             Alter_priv: Y
>           Show_db_priv: Y
>             Super_priv: N
>  Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
>       Lock_tables_priv: Y
>           Execute_priv: Y
>        Repl_slave_priv: N
>       Repl_client_priv: N
>       Create_view_priv: Y
>         Show_view_priv: Y
>    Create_routine_priv: Y
>     Alter_routine_priv: Y
>       Create_user_priv: N
>             Event_priv: Y
>           Trigger_priv: Y
> Create_tablespace_priv: Y
>        account_locked: N
>       Create_role_priv: N
>         Drop_role_priv: N
> ```

Privileges have been flushed and the slave server was started read-only.

```
mysql> select @@read_only;
+-------------+
| @@read_only |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However I can still perform write operations on the slave with the user.

```
mysql> create database foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use foo;

Database changed
mysql> create table `foobar` ( `x` int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into foobar values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into foobar values (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from foobar;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop database foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

It's my understanding that without the Repl and Super priv's I should not be able to do the above, or am I doing something else wrong ?

Essentially I want the scripts and daemons using this login to never break stuff if I flip the master and slave around.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to double check, please run `SHOW GRANTS;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran SHOW GRANTS; as Rick suggested and I had a "CONNECTION_ADMIN" grant.

Removing that seems to have fixed it:

```
create database foo;
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rossi, you don't have to update your "CONNECTION_ADMIN" privilege to make your slave read only for SUPER users like you.

you can set **super_read_only** (available from ***MySQL 5.6.21***) and your server will not allow any updates even for the users that have SUPER privilege.

[super_read_only Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_super_read_only)